# Replace tags into symbol by elementree

Tags: python, xml, elementtree

I have xml like this:

```
<rule>
    <word>I</word>
    <word>need</word>
    <word>more</word>
    <marker>
    <word>money</word>
    </marker>
    <word>now</word>
</rule>
```

I can get the text by:

```
 import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
 tree = ET.parse("1.xml")
 for rule in tree.iter("rule"):
    for word in rule.iter("word"):
        print "%s" % word.text,
```

And I'll get:

```
I need more money now
```

How can I replace marker tags to ( and /marker to ).
In other words result must be:

```
I need more (money) now
```

Is it possible by elementtree? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating over only the `word` children of `rule`, you should iterate over all children of `rule` and act accordingly. The following should give you an idea:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse("1.xml")
for rule in tree.iter("rule"):
    for child in rule:
        if child.tag == 'word':
            print "%s" % child.text
        elif child.tag == 'marker':
            print "("
            for subchild in child:
                if subchild.tag == 'word':
                    print "%s" % subchild.text
            print ")"
```

This can certainly be made more Pythonic but it should give you an idea.

Comment: I used findall, but I doesn't work. Where am I wrong? http://pastebin.com/MTQRPakZ